# Calculate the Area under a Curve

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I would like to calculate the area under a curve to do integration without defining a function such as in `integrate()`.

My data looks as this:

```
Date          Strike     Volatility
2003-01-01    20         0.2
2003-01-01    30         0.3
2003-01-01    40         0.4
etc.
```

I plotted `plot(strike, volatility)` to look at the volatility smile. Is there a way to integrate this plotted "curve"?

Comment: Have a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903092/calculate-auc-in-r

Comment: @Andrie : that's a different type of AUC...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The AUC is approximated pretty easily by looking at a lot of trapezium figures, each time bound between `x_i`, `x_{i+1}`, `y{i+1}` and `y_i`. Using the rollmean of the zoo package, you can do:

```
library(zoo)

x <- 1:10
y <- 3*x+25
id <- order(x)

AUC <- sum(diff(x[id])*rollmean(y[id],2))
```

Make sure you order the x values, or your outcome won't make sense. If you have negative values somewhere along the y axis, you'd have to figure out how exactly you want to define the area under the curve, and adjust accordingly (e.g. using `abs()` )

Regarding your follow-up : if you don't have a formal function, how would you plot it? So if you only have values, the only thing you can approximate is a definite integral. Even if you have the function in R, you can only calculate definite integrals using `integrate()`. Plotting the formal function is only possible if you can also define it.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is there also a way to plot the integral? I mean, if I have a curve such as the volatility smile, I should be able to plot its integral which is a curve as well.

Comment: Thats a great way to test that my pdfs sum to 1. Thanks!

Comment: This is great, but if some values are missing, the formula won't work anymore.

Comment: @DanChaltiel if some values are missing, there's no way of knowing what the real area under the curve is. So that seems not a problem to me. Just remove the missing observations before calculation if you want to disregard the missing data.

Comment: @JorisMeys If you have 10 x values and only 9 y values, you can have a pretty good approximation of AUC if you don't count the missing value. Removing all sample that have only one NA seems a waste for me.

Comment: @DanChaltiel Then you remove the one x value tied to the NA y value. How is that a problem? That's what **every** interpolation method does, my man. How do you think this is done in linear regression?

Comment: Well it is a problem, because as a noob in R I had to struggle for a while to find out how to remove NA values (I just posted it here). Please don't forget R is not very easy to learn. Something you find easy won't be easy to everyone.

Comment: @DanChaltiel That's why it's explained on page 60 of R for Dummies. You can also take a look at `?na.omit`, or this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame

Comment: Fantastic answer. I was doing way complicated to calculate the area under the curve. This gave me the same answer as my complicated function.

Answer (score 43):

Just add the following to your program and you will get the area under the curve:

```
require(pracma)
AUC = trapz(strike,volatility)
```

From `?trapz`:

> This approach matches exactly the approximation for integrating the
>   function using the trapezoidal rule with basepoints x.

Comment: Details are always welcome, especially when an answer has already been accepted.

Comment: Be advised that `trapz()` will give you a negative value if your `x` values are decreasing. See `x<-1:10` vs `x<-10:1`.

Answer (score 24):

Three more options, including one using a spline method and one using Simpson's rule...

```
# get data
n <- 100
mean <- 50
sd <- 50

x <- seq(20, 80, length=n)
y <- dnorm(x, mean, sd) *100

# using sintegral in Bolstad2
require(Bolstad2)
sintegral(x,y)$int

# using auc in MESS
require(MESS)
auc(x,y, type = 'spline')

# using integrate.xy in sfsmisc
require(sfsmisc)
integrate.xy(x,y)
```

The trapezoidal method is less accurate than the spline method, so `MESS::auc` (uses spline method) or `Bolstad2::sintegral` (uses Simpson's rule) should probably be preferred. DIY versions of these (and an additional approach using the quadrature rule) are here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/one-dimensional-integrals/

Comment: There is another package called "flux". It has the same function name that "MESS" has, "auc()". It worth a try!

Answer (score 24):

OK so I arrive a bit late at the party but going over the answers a plain `R` solution to the problem is missing. Here goes, simple and clean:

```
sum(diff(x) * (head(y,-1)+tail(y,-1)))/2
```

The solution for OP then reads as:

```
sum(diff(strike) * (head(volatility,-1)+tail(volatility,-1)))/2
```

This effectively calculates the area using the trapezoidal method by taking the average of the "left" and "right" y-values.

NB: as @Joris already pointed out you could use `abs(y)` if that would make more sense.

Comment: I always prefer plain `R` solutions :)

Answer (score 6):

In the pharmacokinetics (PK) world, calculating different types of AUC is a common and fundamental task. The are lots of different AUC calculations for pharmacokietics, such as

- AUC0-t      = AUC from zero to time t
- AUC0-last   = AUC from zero to the last time point (may be same as above)
- AUC0-inf    = AUC from zero to time infinity
- AUCint      = AUC over a time interval
- AUCall      = AUC over the whole time period for which data exists

One of the best packages which does these calculations is the relatively new package `PKNCA` from the folks at Pfizer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

[Joris Meys's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955118/3888000) was great but I struggled to remove NAs from my samples. Here is the little function I wrote to deal with them :

```
library(zoo) #for the rollmean function

######
#' Calculate the Area Under Curve of y~x
#'
#'@param y Your y values (measures ?)
#'@param x Your x values (time ?)
#'@param start : The first x value 
#'@param stop : The last x value
#'@param na.stop : returns NA if one value is NA
#'@param ex.na.stop : returns NA if the first or the last value is NA
#'
#'@examples 
#'myX = 1:5
#'myY = c(17, 25, NA, 35, 56)
#'auc(myY, myX)
#'auc(myY, myX, na.stop=TRUE)
#'myY = c(17, 25, 28, 35, NA)
#'auc(myY, myX, ex.na.stop=FALSE)
auc = function(y, x, start=first(x), stop=last(x), na.stop=FALSE, ex.na.stop=TRUE){
  if(all(is.na(y))) return(NA)
  bounds = which(x==start):which(x==stop)
  x=x[bounds]
  y=y[bounds]
  r = which(is.na(y))
  if(length(r)>0){
    if(na.stop==TRUE) return(NA)
    if(ex.na.stop==TRUE & (is.na(first(y)) | is.na(last(y)))) return(NA)
    if(is.na(last(y))) warning("Last value is NA, so this AUC is bad and you should feel bad", call. = FALSE) 
    if(is.na(first(y))) warning("First value is NA, so this AUC is bad and you should feel bad", call. = FALSE) 
    x = x[-r]
    y = y[-r]
  }
  sum(diff(x[order(x)])*rollmean(y[order(x)],2))
}
```

I then use it with an apply onto my dataframe : `myDF$auc = apply(myDF, MARGIN=1, FUN=auc, x=c(0,5,10,15,20))`

Hope it can help noobs like me :-)

EDIT : added bounds

Answer (score -6):

You can use ROCR package, where the following lines will give you the AUC:

```
pred <- prediction(classifier.labels, actual.labs)
attributes(performance(pred, 'auc'))$y.values[[1]]
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to compute ROC curve and its AUC, but the area under an arbitrary curve.