# Dependency error in installing packages in R

Tags: r

Hi I am relatively new user of R. Installed R on win8. Now I am trying to install packages but i getting following error:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/Owner/Downloads/pROC_1.5.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘C:/Users/Owner/Downloads/pROC_1.5.4.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependency 'plyr' is not available for package 'pROC'
* removing 'C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/pROC'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\R\win-library\3.0" "C:/Users/Owner/Downloads/pROC_1.5.4.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Owner/Downloads/pROC_1.5.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: You need to install the *plyr* package before. Why do you don't install the packages from CRAN via `install.packages("pROC")`? I don't use windows but AFAIK you will need Rtools to install R packages from local.

Comment: In addition to everything @sgibb said, I recommend upgrading to the latest version of R to make package management simple. It looks like CRAN mirrors maintain packages for R only as far back as R 3.2. You can get packages for older versions, but it will be a lot more work.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the *plyr* package won't make a lot of difference since *pROC* is not supported for your R distribution. 
Also since you use Rstudio you might find it easier to install packages via

```
Tools>Install Packages
```

and then set

```
Install from:
```

to

```
Repository(CRAN).
```

That way you don't have to manually download them. 
As an alternative to *pROC* you can maybe use *ROCR*.
Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954507/calculate-the-area-under-a-curve-in-r) might be of interest if you were planning to use *pROC* to calculate the area under the curve, anyway I'm digressing.

Answer (score 0):

it would appear that the immediate problem is the fact that you are using forward slashes instead of backslashes, were you to change that it would look like this:

```
install.packages("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Downloads\\pROC_1.5.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Good luck!