# AUC of a Precision Recall Curve by using package ROCR

Tags: r, auc, precision-recall

How to obtain AUC (area under curve) of a Precision Recall Curve by using package ROCR..?

```
library(ROCR)
data(ROCR.simple)
pred <- prediction( ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels)
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf)
## precision/recall curve (x-axis: recall, y-axis: precision)
perf1 <- performance(pred, "prec", "rec")
plot(perf1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first get the precision and recall values

```
x <- perf1@x.values[[1]] # Recall values
y <- perf1@y.values[[1]] # Precision values
```

and then  calculate Area under the curve using any of the methods from
[calculate area under the curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954507/calculate-the-area-under-a-curve-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are 2 measures for ROCR. auc and aucpr. This worked for me

**For ROC**

```
perfauc <- performance(pred, "auc")
```

**For PR**

```
perf1auc <- performance(pred, "aucpr")
```

Answer (score -1):

ROCR can calculate AUC directly:

```
perf <- performance(pred, "auc")
```

Get AUC

```
perf@y.values[[1]]
```

Comment: @user-1 and how to get AUC of Precision Recall plot?

Comment: Wasn't that your original question?

Comment: @user-1: In above example code, *perf* is my ROC plot and *perf1* is my Precision-Recall plot. Both of them use the same *pred* object to calculate the curve. I think the answer you gave is the AUC of ROC plot not the Precision-Recall plot. Can you please guide me how to get it?

Comment: Here is how to do it (you have to integrate the function): `f <- approxfun(data.frame(perf1@x.values , perf1@y.values) )

auc <- integrate(f, 0, 1)$value`

Comment: Also, from a different package: AUPRC()  from {PerfMeas}