# Create a ggplot2 stat_ecdf plot with standard error shading

Tags: r, ggplot2, standard-error, ecdf

I have data from three doses of a treatment, with three replicates per each dose:

```
df <- data.frame(dose=c(rep(1,300),rep(3,300),rep(5,300)),
replicate=rep(c(rep("X1",100),rep("X2",100),rep("X3",100)),3),
value=c(rnorm(300,1,1),rnorm(300,3,1),rnorm(300,5,1)),stringsAsFactors=F)

df$dose <- factor(df$dose,levels=c(1,3,5))
```

I want to display it using an cdf plot. Per each replicate I can simply plot the cdfs of the three doses with:

```
for(r in c("X1","X2","X3")){
 ggplot(dplyr::filter(df,replicate==r),aes(x=value,color=dose))+
   stat_ecdf(geom="step")+ 
   theme_bw()+
   theme(panel.border=element_blank(),strip.background=element_blank())
}
```

But I'm looking for a way to display all replicates of each dose in one figure, with standard error shading around the mean value, similar to plots achieved with `stat_smooth`.

Can this be achieved?

Also, either for this or for a single replicate's plot:

```
r <- "X1"
ggplot(dplyr::filter(df,replicate==r),aes(x=value,color=dose))+
  stat_ecdf(geom="step")+ 
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.border=element_blank(),strip.background=element_blank())
```

[image]

Is there a way to compute the area under each of the ecdfs?

Comment: you can get the area under curve; read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954507/calculate-the-area-under-a-curve)

Answer (score 1):

You can use interaction to group the data (in `ggplot`) based on two columns;

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=value,color = interaction(replicate, dose)
            , group=interaction(replicate, dose)))+
stat_ecdf(geom="step")+ 
theme_bw()+
theme(panel.border=element_blank(),strip.background=element_blank())
```

This would be your plot;
[image]

As it is a little bit vague:

if you want to have lines for `dose` then you can get rid of `replicate` in the interaction or use `dose` instead of `replicate` in your `ddplyr::filter`;

```
  ggplot(dplyr::filter(df,dose==1),aes(x=value,color = interaction(replicate, dose)
            , group=interaction(replicate, dose)))+
stat_ecdf(geom="step")+ 
theme_bw()+
theme(panel.border=element_blank(),strip.background=element_blank())
```

And you'd get:

[image]