# How to adjust trapezoidal integration method to a custom zero point?

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I want to calculate the integral of a sequence vector. Since there's no function available, I use the *[trapezoidal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280873/6574038) method*<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule)</sup>.

```
iglTzm <- function(x, y) sum(diff(x) * (head(y, -1) + tail(y, -1))) / 2
```

The first element of the sequence should be the zero point, so the principle is: if the values of the sequence are predominantly below the first value, the integral should be negative, otherwise positive, or 0.

Consider matrix `m1`:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    6    7    8    8    6    8   10
[2,]    9    9    8    9    9    8    9
[3,]    9   10   10    9    9    9    9
[4,]    9    8    8    8    6    8    9
[5,]   10   10   10    9   10    8    0
[6,]    9    8    9   10    9    9    9
```

Integration with these raw values will most likely lead to inconsistent values:

```
> setNames(apply(m1, 1, iglTzm, 0:6), 1:6)
  1   2   3   4   5   6 
 15   2  -2   7 -52   0
```

So I adjust the sequences (rows) on their first value (column 1), in order to set the right signs, and get matrix `m2`:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    1    2    2    0    2    4
[2,]    0    0   -1    0    0   -1    0
[3,]    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0   -1   -1   -1   -3   -1    0
[5,]    0    0    0   -1    0   -2  -10
[6,]    0   -1    0    1    0    0    0
```

Logically that doesn't change anything about the values `iglTzm()` throws, because the `diff()` is the same:

```
> setNames(apply(m2, 1, iglTzm, 0:6), 1:6)
  1   2   3   4   5   6 
 15   2  -2   7 -52   0
```

Anyway, because I can't simply scale or invert it, I haven't had a brilliant idea yet how to adapt the function to get the right signs, which are assumingly:

```
#  1   2   3   4   5   6 
# 15  -2   2  -7 -52   0
```

**Does anyone know how to adapt `iglTzm()` to get the integrals with the correct sign?**

The plot of `m2` should illustrate the principle a bit more:

[image]

---

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(c(6, 7, 8, 8, 6, 8, 10,
                9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 8, 9,
                9, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9,
                9, 8, 8, 8, 6, 8, 9, 
                10, 10, 10, 9, 10, 8, 0, 
                9, 8, 9, 10, 9, 9, 9), 6, byrow=TRUE)

m2 <- t(apply(m1, 1, function(x) scale(x, center=x[1], scale=FALSE)))

# plot
par(mfrow=c(2, 3))
lapply(1:nrow(m2), function(x) {
  plot(m2[x, ], type="l", main=x)
  abline(h=m2[x, 1], col="red", lty=2)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is another small but more important issue, although after fixing it your question would still remain valid. What I mean is that the order of `x` and `y` as arguments of your function should be reversed due to how you use the function in `apply`.

But that is not enough and now we come back to your question. For that, let us recall the usual integration: ʃf(x)dx (with limits from a to b) would integrate the area below f, which is what your function already successfully does. Now what you want is to adjust its level. But if we integrate from a to b, that is the same as ʃ(f(x)-f(a))dx = ʃf(x)dx - (b-a)f(a), which leads to

```
iglTzm <- function(y, x) sum(diff(x) * (head(y, -1) + tail(y, -1))) / 2 - y[1] * (max(x) - min(x))
setNames(apply(m1, 1, iglTzm, 0:6), 1:6)
#  1  2  3  4  5  6 
#  9 -2  2 -7 -8  0
```

It happens that only two absolute values are different from the version where `x` and `y` are reversed. Bet let's look at the first function: should it be 9 or 15? We have that 2*2/2 + 1*2 + 1*2/2 + 2*4/2 = 9, so indeed we want to reverse `x` and `y`.

Another way to write the function would be

```
iglTzm <- function(y, x) sum(diff(x) * (head(y - y[1], -1) + tail(y - y[1], -1))) / 2
setNames(apply(m1, 1, iglTzm, 0:6), 1:6)
#  1  2  3  4  5  6 
#  9 -2  2 -7 -8  0
```

**Edit**: by reversing I only meant the order in the function definition or how you use it in `apply`; the function itself in terms of y (function values) and x (grid values) is fine.

Comment: Hola! I have noticed the strange values but i have not really realized the error. But I believe the order now is better and can be intuitively used with `apply` or other functions with similar architecture. I'm sure the mix-up happened because I was using `integrate()` before. And now - regardless to your already great answer - in this point I have an intuition problem: `integrate(function(x) x, 0, 1)` and `iglTzm(0:1, 0:1)`yield the same, whereas `iglTzm(0:10, 0:1)` is different, but shouldn't it be equal? We integrate in all cases from 0 to 1, and all slopes are equal. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @jay.sf, `iglTzm(0:10, 0:1)` is wrong (due to recycling you get no warnings/errors). You have 11 function values 0, 1, ..., 10, whereas you give only two grid points 0, 1. So where does the function take value 3, 6, 10? Now `iglTzm(0:10, seq(0, 1, length = 11))` would be correct integration from 0 to 1, but the slopes aren't the same. The slope of 0:1 is 1, while the slope of 0:10, is 10. (Due to recycling, `iglTzm(0:10, 0:1)` is the same as `iglTzm(0:10, 0:10)`.)

Comment: Ah recycling! Ok, but when I `plot(0:1)`  and `plot(0:10)` both slopes should be the same, and also both integrals from 0 to 1 are the same, aren't they? Maybe I'm lacking something.

Comment: @jay.sf, `plot(0:1)` corresponds to f(x)=x for the range of `x` as [0,1], while `plot(0:10)` the same function with the range [0,10]. The integral of the first one then is 1*1/2=1, while the second one 10*10/2=50 (they are just two triangles). There seems to be some confusion between `x` and `y` that you pass to `iglTzm`, `x` and `y` in terms of f(x)=y as actual functions, and possible what a slope is (e.g., by rescaling the plot the slope may look different, but it isn't).

Comment: Yeah, I think your words cut the knot in my head. I really appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: @jay.sf, no problem, I'm glad it helps. (I also have a typo: 1*1/2=1/2, not 1.)

Comment: I've noticed that ;)