# Area under ROC in R

Tags: r, data-mining, auc

Is there a way of calculating or estimating the area under the curve as an external metric, using base R, from confusion matrices alone?

If not, how would I do it, given the clustering object?

e.g. we can start from

```
cutree(hclust(dist(iris[,1:4])),method="average"),3))
```

or, from a diagonal-maximized version of

```
table(iris$Species, cutree(hclust(dist(iris[,1:4])),method="average"),3))
```

the latter being the confusion matrix. I would much, much prefer a solution that goes from the confusion matrix but if it's impossible we can use the clustering object itself.

I read the comments here: [Calculate AUC in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903092/calculate-auc-in-r) -- the top solution looks good, but it's unclear to me how to generalise it for multi-class data like `iris`.

(No packages, obviously, I want to find out how to do it by hand in base R)